# How can I play sounds in specified times? (Simulating recording in my app)

Tags: android, soundpool

I want to implement recording in my piano app. to do this, I save the time of playing of each sound and which one was played in a LinkedList. To play the recorded music(sequence of sounds) with this times and sounds, we should play each sound at its specified time. How do this?
here is a part of my code for one sound(note):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

double StartTime;
double millis;
sound_pool snd;
LinkedList<list> rec_list = new LinkedList<list>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Create an instance of our sound manger
    snd = new sound_pool(getApplicationContext());
    // Set volume rocker mode to media volume
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);       
    Date dt=new Date();
    long mil=dt.getTime();

    btn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) 

               {
                snd.play_s_r_1();                   
                Date dt=new Date();
                long mil=dt.getTime();                  
                rec_list.add(new list(mil,"s_r_1"));        
               }
             return true;                   
        }
    });  // end of ontouch listener 

} //end of oncreate
} //end of activity
```

Answer (score 0):

just try following code 
public CountDownTimer (long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)
millisInFuture - The number of millis in the future from the call to start() until the countdown is done and onFinish() is called. So onFinish() will be called after 1 second (1000 millisecond = 1second).

```
   player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.beepsound);
 player.start();

CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
   // Nothing to do
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    if (player.isPlaying()) {
         player.stop();
         player.release();
    }
}
};
timer.start();
```

Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#CountDownTimer(long, long)

Comment: @Prablu
Thank you.
can I play a sequence of 500 sounds with this code?

Comment: if you call each and every sound through above logic  .it is possible i thing.